# how to add background color to UIbuttons crested by using for loop based on frame sizes?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have created 5 buttons using for loop based on incrementing y axis value in `CGRectMake`. But how can i change the background color of button when i clicked each button?and also title AND having alertview for each button??pls suggest me answer..

```
//array taken for button titles
NSArray *array1=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5", nil];

int k=0;  

for(int i=50;i<=350;i=i+70)
{
  button=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
  button.frame=CGRectMake(30,i,35,40);
  [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonclicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  if (k<[array1 count])
  {
    [button setTitle:[array1 objectAtIndex:k] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  }
  k++;  
  [self.view addSubview:button]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 -(void) buttonClicked:(id) sender
{
  UIButton * button = (UIButton*) sender;
   button.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowcolor];
   [button setTitle:@"Hello" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `tag` for each button and when it's call buttonclicked: is called, then use it's `tag` rod decide which background color to set it to::

```
int temptag;
temptag = 0;
for(int i=50;i<=350;i=i+70)
{
  button=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
  button.frame=CGRectMake(30,i,35,40);
  [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonclicked:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  button.tag = temptag;
  if (k<[array1 count])
  {
    [button setTitle:[array1 objectAtIndex:k] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  }
  k++;  
  temptag++;
  [self.view addSubview:button]; 
}


-(void)buttonclicked:(id)sender
{
  UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
  switch (btn.tag) {
    case 0:
      btn.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
      break;
    case 1:
      btn.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
      break;
    case ...:
      ....
    default:
      break;
    }
}
```